# faulthandler.enable() in a library for production use?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-c-api

I have a Python C Extension wrapped with a Python library. While testing, I've been using `faulthandler.enable()` in the Python library to debug segfaults in the C Extension.

Now that I'm ready to put this code into production, should I remove this from the library? I assume it has some sort of overhead to it. However if there is some hidden bug, it would be nice if this was on and caught the stack trace.